# how to check database value and input value is equal in laravel-4

Tags: date, laravel-4

this is my database table attendence fields are id  studid ,adate,amonth ,ayear,acls_id, attendence and field values are below.

```
id  studid  adate   amonth  ayear   acls_id attendence      
 1       28     02       07     2015       10       1     
 2       31     02       07     2015       10       1   
 4       32     02       07     2015       10       1   
 5       28     13       07     2015       10       1 

 6       31     13       07     2015       10       1   
 7       32     13       07     2015       10       1   
 9       28     14       07     2015       10       1   
 10      31     14       07     2015       10       1   
 11      32     14       07     2015       10       1   
13       28     15       07     2015       10       1   
14       31     15       07     2015       10       0   
15       32     15       07     2015       10       1   
17       28     16       07     2015       10       0   
18       31     16       07     2015       10       1   
19       32     16       07     2015       10       1   
21       28     17       07     2015       10       1   
22       31     17       07     2015       10       1   
23       32     17       07     2015       10       0   
24       28     20       08     2015       10       1   
25       31     20       08     2015       10       1   
26       32     20       08     2015       10       0
```

I want to display like pivot table format.

when im select month and year and check  that month and year in database.if yes display values like this pivot table form

eg:july 2015

```
studid date1 date2 date3..date13 date14 date15 date16 date17.....date31

 28     x       1     x     1      1      1      0    1       x x x..x

 31     x       1     x     1      1      1      1    1       x x x..x

 32     x       1     x     1      1      1      1    0       x x x..x
```

my controller code is

```
        $amonth = Input::get('amonth');
        $ayear = Input::get('ayear');
        $dayCount = date('t', strtotime('01-'. $amonth . '-' . $ayear));
        $days = [];
        for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++) {
         $days[] = $i; }           
        $attendence_tbl = WysAttendancename::where('cls_id',$id)->first();
        $wys_attendence_table = $attendence_tbl->attendance_name;
        $attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                      ->where('amonth','=',$amonth)
                      ->where('ayear','=',$ayear) 
                      ->get();`
```

my view .blade.php

```
<td>Teacher Name</td>
@for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++)
<td>{{$i}}</td>
@endfor
</tr>
@foreach($teacher as $teachers)
<tr>   
<td>{{$teachers->tname}}</td>
@foreach($attendance as $attendances)
@if($teachers->id == $attendances->t_auserid)  
@if($attendances->t_attendance == 1)
<td><font color="green">p</font></td>
@elseif($attendances->t_attendance == 0)
<td><font color="red">a</font></td>    
@endif
@endif
@endforeach 
@endforeach
```

its work fine but problem is couldn't check the month day(eg :adate-2) is in exist in database or not .

iam using display full month in column ,code is

```
$dayCount = date('t', strtotime('01-'. $amonth . '-' . $ayear));
$days = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++) {
$days[] = $i; } `
```

in my database 1/07/2015 is not but in view page display 2/70/2015 value in 1/07/2015 and also 13/07/2015 value in 3/107/2015 ...

I want to dislpay like above  pivot table form 
 how to change my code to check databse adate and month day($i)???